# Permute Layer: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two sensor inputs for which I have applied the Concatenate layer previously for fusion. Both of them are time series data for which I'm now trying to apply a permutation layer. However, when I do so, I get the error:

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv1d_334/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d_334/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d_334/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,2,6249], [1,3,6249,128].

My inputs are both time series data with input dimension `(1176, 6249, 1)`. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is a sample code:

```
lr = 0.0005
n_timesteps = 3750
n_features = 1
n_outputs = 3

def small_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
    signal1 = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1:]))
    signal2 = Input(shape=(X_train_phase.shape[1:]))
    
    concat_signal = Concatenate()([signal1, signal2])
    
    # x = InputLayer(input_shape=(None, X_train.shape[1:][0],1))(inputA)
    
    x = Permute(dims=(2, 1))(concat_signal)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x) #, input_shape=(None, 3750, n_features)
    x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you get to the convolution, your time dimension (2) is smaller than the filter that you have specified (5).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Permute
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D


# dummy data w/batch 32
X_train = tf.random.normal([32, 6249, 1])
X_train_phase = tf.random.normal([32, 6249, 1])
    
signal1 = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1:]))
signal2 = Input(shape=(X_train_phase.shape[1:]))

concat_signal = Concatenate()([signal1, signal2])

x = Permute(dims=(2, 1))(concat_signal)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

print(x.shape)
# (None, 2, 6249)
```

If you see the docs for [`tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D), you'll notice that `"valid"` is the default padding, which means there is no padding. There is a great reference, ["A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep
learning"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf), which does a good job of illustrating the relationship between input size, kernel size, strides, and padding.

While I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this network, adding the argument `padding="same"` to your convolution layers will send the input through without issue.

```py
x = Conv1D(
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=5,
    activation="relu",
    padding="same",  # <= add this.
    kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(x)
```